# how to use plantUML after installing PowerTools?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, programming, flatpak

On the [understanding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596469/101935) that `PowerTools` [includes](http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/8-stream/PowerTools/x86_64/os/Packages/) `plantUML` I've [installed](https://serverfault.com/q/997896/579182) and enabled the package.

How do I now invoke `plantUML` to use it?

(Although I now realize that the above link is actually for `CentOS` stream, whereas I'm running `CentOS`.)

Comment: Oh, I see.  It's a repo.  This has plant UML?

Comment: For the record, if you are curious about the contents of a package, if it is installed, just run `rpm -ql $PACKAGENAME`. (Where $PACKSGENAME is the name of the package). It will tell you what the executable name is, because it will be in /usr/bin/.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, there’s no plantuml package in Centos. I there’s a Fedora package, maybe it can be rebuilt for C8.